# Codeigniter seperate front-end and back-end

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm currently learning myself the Codeigniter framework. I want to create a project that will have a front-end (which will be used by users) and a back-end (which would be used by administrators).

I have looked through different articles, all of them suggest using HMVC to separate the public and admin controllers/views. I have also considered to create two separate projects, one for the public and one for the admin, both using the same database.

I have tried to do research on which one of the methods mentioned above would be the best solution for a potentially large project, but could not come up with any sustainable answer.

Is it possible that two separate CodeIgniter projects can access and use the same database simultaneously?

Edit:
The client project would mostly just query the database for results, whereas the admin project would be full CRUD.

If indeed creating multiple projects would be the recommended way to go, the admin project would be running on a sub-domain i.e admin.example.com whilst the client project would be running on example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid to use any of the approaches you mention. It is a matter of personal preference (read: opinion). I have used each singly and in combination with more or less the same outcome. I have settled on using none of the above. Instead, I use a single project, no HMVC, no subdomains, standard CI file structure. I feel keeping it simple ultimately makes it easier to build and maintain. YMMV.

What separates the public-users from admin-users is **authentication** and **authorization** (A&A). Nobody gets into an admin controller without the proper login credentials and permissions. You're going to need A&A anyway to keep the public from accidentally discovering the admin area. IMO, a "special" file structure and subdomains actually make implementing A&A harder.

Depending on your deadline for this project you might want to look at using [CodeIgniter Version 4](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/#). It's a thoroughly modern revamp of the framework. It is still in beta test mode, but I've found it to be quite stable. They are working hard to get to the release version. There is no published release date yet, but all indications are it will be sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

The answer as to how to configure CI is really dependent on your needs and what you feel is best. There is no *right* answer or "acceptable" way of doing things in this regard.

When I first started with Codeigniter, I had just a sub-folder for backend controllers called `admin` as well as an `Admin` base/core controller that all admin classes extended rather than `CI_Controller`. Models/views can be similarly organized in to sub-folders. This was a perfectly acceptable solution in my opinion for small-scale applications.

I moved in to HMVC and found that it really isn't that much different in terms of keeping them both separate. Although you can easily drag-and-drop modules from different projects so long as they are decoupled, you'll still have to jump through hoops to get front/back ends separate. I believe I used this is a starting point: https://github.com/jmtolibas/HMVC-CI3-with-Separate-Backend-and-Frontend

In terms of what you mentioned, having 2 separate projects wouldn't necessarily be a bad idea. You could even share the same system folder with a modification in `index.php` regarding the system path. Multiple database connections shouldn't be an issue.

So basically, all 3 approach will work, it is up to you to determine which one you like working with the most.

If you want my opinion, I would use Laravel or Lumen on any new project, and separation of front/back end is rather easy with packages, namespacing, .etc.